# The actual polynomial behind a BezierFunction

Tags: polynomials, parametric-functions, implementation-details, splines

Let's say I have the following Mathematica code

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}};
F = BezierFunction[pts]
```

How can I find the actual polynomial of the `BezierFunction` object?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, it is not. I know how to form a bezier function from Bernstein polynomials. Instead, I want to expand the `BezierFunction` to its actual underlying polynomial. The same results, but in different ways. There are a lot of built-in function objects in mathematica. It would be good to know how to "see" and use their actual symbolic function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference. `BezierFunction` probably uses a numerical routine such as de Casteljau's algorithm. (Consider `InputForm[F]`, that symbolic evaluation is not carried out, and `WorkingPrecision -> Infinity` is not allowed.) If so, there is no actual underlying polynomial or symbolic function, except that the numerical routine is equivalent to computing symbolic polynomials, which you already know how to derive. If you're not asking for the actual numerical routine, does it matter how the symbolic function is derived, since it is equivalent to any other one?

Comment: Would it make sense instead to work with the Bernstein basis functions?

Comment: If you just want the polynomials themselves, then as already noted, use the explicit expansion in terms of `BernsteinBasis[]`. Otherwise, whatever gave you the notion that `BezierFunction[]` isn't internally using something like de Casteljau, instead of actually expanding the polynomial before evaluating?